# python-django проблемы с кодировкой

Tags: python, кодировка, django

добрый день!
делаю форму поиска
html:

```
 <form action='/notebook/search/' method='get'>
      <input type='text' name='q'>
      <input type='submit' value='Найти'>
 </form>
```

обрабатываю запрос:
vews.py:

```
def note_search(request):
    """ поиск записи """
    if 'q' in request.GET:
        q = request.GET['q']
        notebook = request.user.notebooks.filter(Q(surname=q))
        message = 'Вы ищете запись %r' % (request.GET['q'])
    else:
        message = 'Строка не должна быть пустой'
        notebook = request.user.notebooks.all()
    return render_to_response('notebook.html',
                         {'notebook': notebook, 'message': message},
                           RequestContext(request))
```

проблема в том, что далее в шаблоне {{ message }} отображается как

```
Вы ищете запись u'\u041c\u0430\u043a\u0441'
```

а хотелось бы увидеть

```
Вы ищете запись Макс
```

потому как в строке поиска я набрал слово "Макс".

Как мне сделать читаемый вывод message?
Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы видите «`u'\u041c\u0430\u043a\u0441'`», потому что так работает `repr`, который Вы использовали, указав «`%r`».

Несколько костыльно, но вполне будет работать:

```
    ...
    message = u'Вы ищете запись «%s»' % request.GET['q']
else:
    message = u'Строка не должна быть пустой'
...
```

(Префиксы `u` — чтобы все было чище, и байтовые «строки» не смешивались с Unicode.)

Но более правильно, как мне кажется, будет передать это `q` в шаблон, а там уже выводить сообщения:

```
{% if query %}
    Вы ищете запись «{{ query }}»
{% else %}
    Выведены все записи
{% endif %}
```